# Having an issue with getting unicode to parse with json_encode

Tags: php, json, character-encoding

I've read through all the questions I could find on here, and but none of the examples I've found have worked, current have a script returning the following json:

```
{
    "clickid": "24231527",
    "geo_data": {
        "country_code": "FR",
        "state": "Paris",
        "city": "Paris",
        "currency_symbol": "\u0080",
        "currency_code": "EUR"
    }
}
```

I've tried all of the following, but I keep getting either a square box, or question mark when I try to convert it to UTF-8:

```
header('content-type:text/html;charset=utf-8');
$data = json_decode($output, false, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
$geo_data->{"currency_symbol"} = utf8_encode($geo_data->{"currency_symbol"});
```

Every combination I try to get it to print the ‎‎€ is either returning a box (withont the encode) or a ? (with the encode).

Comment: If I'm not mistaken .... shouldn't the `€` be `\u20ac` instead?

Comment: https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0080/index.htm

Comment: It's what the encode is generating on the source page

Comment: But you want Euro, right? https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/20ac/index.htm

Comment: If I encode the wrong character, it is the wrong character decoded. If I use the euro `€` character, when I do a base `json_encode($object);`, the json comes out with `"currency_symbol":"\u20ac"` ... and then if I `json_decode($json)` that json, it comes back out as the euro. I think the issue is the source you are working with.

Comment: please read the **[json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)** documentation, your use of parameter 3 makes no sense. It would however make sense to use a `json_encode` option of `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE` to produce the json you are using in this code snippet. Show how you produced that.